# How do you use views.py to display mysql data in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am a beginner in python and am trying the tutorial below:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/

I have created a template with the following body:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>First Blog</h1>
    <hr />
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <h3>Posted on {{ post.timestamp }} by {{ post.author }}</h3>
        <p>{{ post.bodytext }}</p>
        </div>
        <hr />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The views.py document has the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from blog.models import posts
def home(request):
    entries = posts.objects.all()[:10]
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'posts' : entries})
```

The website displays the following:

```
First Blog

{% for post in posts %}
{{ post.title }}

Posted on {{ post.timestamp }} by {{ post.author }}

{{ post.bodytext }}

{% endfor %}
```

How do I get the website to display the data from my database?

Comment: What exactly are you having problem with? Are you having app server and db server running?

Comment: Did you use the entire template in the example (the full HTML file) or just that portion of it?

Comment: Seems like you are just opening the template on your browser. You need to access via an URL defined on your URLConf. Did you start the development server?

Comment: Are you on production like apache? Is mod_wsgi installed?

Comment: Sushant, currently I am running the dev server by entering the command: 
~/dev/firstblog$ python manage.py runserver. 

I used just the div portion of the html file, there is also the standard header.

Cesar, in my settings.py documents I have my URLConf as follows, is there a problem here?
ROOT_URLCONF = 'FirstBlog.urls'

*from urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
     url(r'^$', 'FirstBlog.blog.views.home', name='home'),

Comment: Jingo, I have the wsgi.py file which was added by Django when I started the project:
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "FirstBlog.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()